# Multiple sessions issue in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a portal in which i have two "pages" , one in which enter normal users and one like this /admin where admin enters. I'm ussing sessions but the problem is that once a user is logged in he/she can access even the admin area and vice versa. Why is that?

How would i prevent it?

Thanks.

The check_login

```
<?php
define(DOC_ROOT,dirname(__FILE__)); // To properly get the config.php file
$username = $_POST['username']; //Set UserName
$password = $_POST['password']; //Set Password
$msg ='';
if(isset($username, $password)) {
    ob_start();
    include(DOC_ROOT.'/config.php'); //Initiate the MySQL connection
    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($username);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $myusername);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM login_admin WHERE user_name='$myusername' and user_pass=SHA1('$mypassword')";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbC, $sql);
    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "admin.php"
        session_register("admin");
        session_register("password");
        $_SESSION['name']= $myusername;
        header("location:index.php");
    }
    else {
        $msg = "Wrong Username or Password. Please retry";
        header("location:login.php?msg=$msg");
    }
    ob_end_flush();
}
else {
    header("location:login.php?msg=Please enter some username and password");
}
?>
```

What i insert before every page:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Start the session
define(ADMIN,$_SESSION['name']); //Get the user name from the previously registered super global variable
if(!session_is_registered("admin")){ //If session not registered
header("location:login.php"); // Redirect to login.php page
}
else //Continue to current page
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
?>
```

Comment: Although I wish mind reading was a talent on mine, you're going to have to provide some code so we can help you out.

Comment: how you decide whether a user is admin or normal user

Comment: I have put them in separate folders, the code, but i intend to insert just one now, just one login!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user has successfully authorized check if he is an admin or normal user. So let's say for the admin user you define an admin session variable

```
$_SESSION['admin_user'] = True
```

Then before displaying the admin section just check if the user has the right permissions.

```
if ($_SESSION['admin_user']) {
       // display admin content
}
else {
      print("Not available, you need admin privilege.");
}
```

So based on your code I would modified it to look something like that:

```
<?php
  session_start(); //Start the session
  if( isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin_user'] ){ //If session registered and admin
     header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
     // more content
   }
  else 
     header("location: login.php"); // Redirect to login.php page
?>
```

Also [session_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) is deprecated and from php 5.4 removed, so use $_SESSION['variable_name'] instead.

Comment: Yes, but how is the site going to recognize if the user is an admin, i'll have to do any check?

Comment: Add another column in your database to define which user is admin and retrieve the value when you check his/her username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Make two session variable like

```
$_SESSION['user']//can access only one page
$_SESSION['admin']//can access both
```

and check their existence by `isset($_session['user'])` or `isset($_session['admin'])`

Comment: Can you please check my updated code in order to tell me where to put this lines?

Answer (score -1):

this is what you should do:

```
    // and 956 in ur db is admin, user enters the userID in login

    if(_SESSION['userID']=="956")
     {

            redirect_to("localhost/admin.php");
     }
     else
     {
            redirect_to ("localhost/home.php");

      }
```

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode userID's and their roles in your code.  What if you ever wanted a second admin?  Or port your code to another server and start with new id-numbers, ...

Comment: i just wrote it , to give him an idea. Should have mentioned it